# how to check if the user who puts a product is the one who modifies it with the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

my mentor want me to check if the user who put a sauce on the app is the same user who want to modify. he tells me i can use a condition i di!d it but nothing works

here is the code section:

```
exports.updateSauce = (req, res, next) => {
    //console.log (req);
    //recherche de la sauce dont l'id est en paramètre
    sauce.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
        .then((sauce) => {
            //teste si l'id du créateur de la sauce est le même que l'id du requeteur
            if (sauce.userId !== req.auth.userId) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    error: new Error('Requête non autorisée !')
                })
            }
            // ok, c'est le même                               
            console.log("OK");

            // effaçons le fichier image d'origine si l'on change d'image
            if (req.file) {  //si une image est upload
                const last_filename = sauce.imageUrl.split('/images/')[1];
                console.log(last_filename);
                fs.unlink(`images/${last_filename}`, () => {
                    console.log("FICHIER EFFACE");
                    const sauceObject = { ...JSON.parse(req.body.sauce), imageUrl: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}` };
                    console.log(sauceObject);
                    console.log(req.params.id);
                    sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { ...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
                        .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: 'Sauce modifiée !' }))
                        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("SANS FICHIER MODIFIE");
                console.log(req.body);
                const sauceObject = { ...req.body };
                console.log(req.params.id);
                sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { ...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("updated");
                        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Sauce modifiée !' })
                    }
                    )
                    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
            }



        }
        );
```

Comment: what is `req.auth.userId`? what is `sauce.userId`? Make sure you are not comparing an `ObjectId` with a `string`

Comment: In what way does this "not work"?  When you debug, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: @Pipe sauce is: const sauce = require('../models/sauce');
auth is const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

sauce is an Object the other is just my middleware/auth

Comment: @Edwin i was actually asking by its data types... make sure they are equal

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine but it might not work if one is an objectID and the other is a string, Can you check which might be a string in the section below:

```
if (sauce.userId !== mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.auth.userId)) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: new Error('Requête non autorisée !')
   })
```

Can you log these two sauce.userId & req.auth.userId and share the output?

Comment: I can't log them it doesn't work when i try

Comment: req.auth.userId is a string

Comment: That might be it try this: `if (sauce.userId !== mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.auth.userId)) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: new Error('Requête non autorisée !')
   })`

Comment: I edited the original answer by wrapping the req.auth.userId with mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.auth.userId)

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to convert objectId to string before compare:

```
if (sauce.userId.toString() !== req.auth.userId) { //If req.auth.userId is string as you said
     return res.status(401).json({
         error: new Error('Requête non autorisée !')
     });
}
```